# Overload resolution for iterator types: a simpler way?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to reimplement the `std::vector` class using only C++03 techniques (for educational purposes), and have run into a problem with the `std::vector::assign` method, declared in two forms:

```
void assign(size_type count, const_reference value);

template<class In>
void assign(In first, In last);
```

Upon instantiation the compiler seems to prefer the second form, leading to errors of the form:

```
In instantiation of 'void dojo::vector<T>::assign(In, In) [with In = int; T = int]':
error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
    push_back(*first++);
```

I believe I need to give the compiler a hint that the `In` template type should only be bound to iterator types, so that the second form of the method will only be chosen during overload resolution when called with iterators. However, providing such a hint seems somewhat complicated. GNU's libstdc++ uses something called `__is_integer`:

```
510         template<typename _InputIterator>
511         void
512         assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
513         {
514           // Check whether it's an integral type.  If so, it's not an iterator.
515           typedef typename std::__is_integer<_InputIterator>::__type _Integral;
516           _M_assign_dispatch(__first, __last, _Integral());
517         }
```

and llvm's libc++ uses `enable_if`, which looks even more complex and is only available since C++11:

```
1363    template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
1364    template <class _InputIterator>
1365    typename enable_if
1366    <
1367         __is_input_iterator  <_InputIterator>::value &&
1368        !__is_forward_iterator<_InputIterator>::value &&
1369        is_constructible<
1370           _Tp,
1371           typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::reference>::value,
1372        void
1373    >::type
1374    vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
1375    {
1376        clear();
1377        for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
1378            push_back(*__first);
1379    }
```

Is there a simpler way that's compatible with C++03?

Comment: libstdc++'s way is about as easy as it gets.

Comment: Thanks, after reading this blog post (http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/sfinae-and-enable_if/) it seems that `enable_if` isn't so complex, after all.

Comment: `enable_if` itself is easy to write; the harder part is writing the traits used in the condition.